# For loop in views

Tags: django

In views I want to get car-object, then change `first_year` var.

```
def cars(request, mark_id, year=year):
        #BMW, etc.
    mark = get_object_or_404(Mark, pk=mark_id, active=1)
        #M, X-series, etc.
    for group in mark.groups.iterator():
        group.first_year.year = int(year)-int(group.first_year.year)
    return render(request, 'cars.html', {  'mark':mark, })
```

So, in template I use:

```
{% for i in mark.groups.all %}

{{i.first_year}}

{% endfor %}
```

And it returns the values from db, not my `group.first_year.year`. As you can understand, there is 3 models - mark, groups and first_year. If you need, I can publish they here, but I think, that something wrong in my views.

Thanks.

**Edit. Models.**

```
class First_Year(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.year)

class Groups(models.Model):
        many_other_fields
    mark = models.ForeignKey(Mark, related_name='groups')
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()
    first_year = models.ForeignKey(First_Year, related_name='first_year')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    def altered_date(self, year):
        altered_year = int(year)-int(self.first_year.year)
        return altered_year
```

Without model Mark, bacause it has many-many fields without year and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop making changes in your view is not saving the changes anywhere so you will not see the changes when the values are passed to your template.

One solution here is to add a new model method to your model and do the date comparison there.

In your `First_Year` model add the `altered_date` function like so:

```
class First_Year(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.year)
    def altered_date(self, this_year):
        altered_year = int(this_year)-int(self.year)
        return altered_year
```

This gets the altered year for every `First_Year` model by calling the function. Unfortunately this function requires an additional parameter - `year` - so it cannot be called directly from the template. You can create a custom template filter to get around this:

```
@register.filter
def get_altered_year(obj, gar):
    return obj.altered_date(gar)
```

Now you just need to make sure that you pass year to your view by modifying your return like so:

```
def cars(request, mark_id, year=year):
    ...
    return render(request, 'cars.html', {'mark':mark, 'year':year, })
```

And then in your template you can do:

```
{% for i in mark.groups_set.all %}
    {{i.first_year|get_altered_year:year }}
{% endfor %}
```

You can look at the model method documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#model-methods). And the documentation for custom template filters [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters).

Comment: but it doesnt work correct: `int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'First_Year'`, because I have First_Year-model, I try `altered_year = int(year)-int(self.first_year.year)`, and it returns `'long' object has no attribute 'altered_date'`

Comment: My answer is tailored to the year field being in your groups model. You should put the `altered_year` function on whichever model has the `date`. If it's the `First_Year` model then put the function there and adjust my answer accordingly. Or post your models.

Comment: I updated my post to reflect putting the model function on the `First_Year` model. I also changed the template code to reflect the join.

Answer (score 0):

You mean:

```
{% for i in mark.groups_set.all %}
   {{i.first_year}}
{% endfor %}
```

This will only allow if groups has a foreign key from mark

Comment: yes, groups - its a related_name. And code returns values from db, not  from views