# Expected a character buffer object

Tags: python, django

Models in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137356/for-loop-in-views). In admin.py:

```
class GroupsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['first_year', 'many other']}),

    ]
```

So, in this admin section I can add `first_year` to the special series of cars. I press "+", then opens a new window - where I can add the year. I add '2011', press "Save" and see the error:

```
TypeError: expected a character buffer object.
```

Its very strange, because it works at last week. How it fix? If I go to the `first_yearAdmin`, and add the year, it works without errors.

Thanks.

Edit. Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/cars/first_year/add/?_popup=1

Django Version: 1.5
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'cars',
 'django_evolution',
 'django.contrib.admin')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  372.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  89.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  202.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  25.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  21.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  223.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  1010.                 return self.response_add(request, new_object)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in response_add
  833.                 (escape(pk_value), escapejs(obj)))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in wrapper
  194.             return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/html.py" in escapejs
  65.     return mark_safe(force_text(value).translate(_js_escapes))

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/cars/first_year/add/
Exception Value: expected a character buffer object
```

**Models**

```
class Mark(models.Model):
    many_many_char_fields
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class First_Year(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.year)

class Groups(models.Model):
        many_other_fields
    mark = models.ForeignKey(Mark, related_name='groups')
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()
    first_year = models.ForeignKey(First_Year, related_name='first_year')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    def altered_date(self, year):
        altered_year = int(year)-int(self.first_year.year)
        return altered_year
```

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: {'fields': ['first_year', 'many other'],}),

Comment: @catherine it doesnt work, I comment `fieldsets`, try to add new year and has the same error

Comment: @tim can you send me your whole project? I will try to fix it

Comment: @catherine I cant, because its not Open Source (at this time). It error apears, when I remove Django 1.4 and install 1.5

Comment: @tim that's ok I will just try to analyze what you have post, maybe I can see something.

Comment: Can you post your models?

Comment: @tim In your first year model change it to: return "{0}".format(self.year)

Comment: year = models.IntegerField(max_digits=4)

Comment: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_digits'`

Comment: @catherine  with `max_length` it works without `__init__()-error`.But the sme error - `expected a character buffer object`

Comment: @tim OK I think I know the reason of your problem, I hope so. In your First_Year model you have only 1 field who use IntegerField which Django not allowed to return in the unicode. TypeError characted buffer is from your str. So try to change the field into CharField, delete your database and sync again

Comment: year = models.CharField(max_length=4), To check if the the year is charfield go to your database

Comment: @catherine I have done all, what you say, and `return self.year `, it works!!! Thank you very much, its great!

Comment: @tim can I post my answer?

Comment: I get the same error, downgrading to Django 1.4.5 fixed it, this definitely seems to be a regression in Django 1.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class First_Year(models.Model):
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.year
```

Answer (score 9):

Actually, it is not necessary to transform the `year` field into Charfield, if you want to keep it Integer, as it would be impossible in many cases where you really need a number. The workaround for this 1.5 bug is to make `__unicode__` function return unicode string:

```
class First_Year(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.year)
```

Answer (score 0):

you forget this

```
class GroupsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Groups
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the fields key have to receive a list of lists or a list of tuples, so, you have to do this: `{'fields': ['first_year', 'many other'],}` just put a comma after the dict